# Js filter on condition if exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I would like to filter array on some condition using "filter" method. If only one condition is active there is no problem. But if object in array must be under two condition there is a problem.

```
getFilteredItems() {
      let customText = this.filters.customTextFilter.trim();
      return this.filteredItems.filter((x) => {

        if (customText !== '') {
          return x.name.includes(customText) || x.code.includes(customText) || x.city.includes(customText);
        }

        if (this.filters.currencySelected !== '') {
          return x.currency === this.filters.currencySelected;
        }
        return true;
      })
    }
```

How to join both condition if both are selected? I have another 3 conditions to join. So if some one select two condition how to check both in object and return true if both are true?

Thank you

Comment: `if (condition1 && condition2)`

Comment: return true only if all condition are satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `result` variable and set to false when ever condition is not satisfied and return the result

```
getFilteredItems() {

          let customText = this.filters.customTextFilter.trim();
          return this.filteredItems.filter((x) => {
            result=true;
            if (customText !== '') {
              result = result &&( x.name.includes(customText) || x.code.includes(customText) || x.city.includes(customText));
            }

            if (this.filters.currencySelected !== '') {
              result = result &&( x.currency === this.filters.currencySelected);
            }
            return result;
          })

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array, which holds your filters, and use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to iterate over it:

```js
const filteredItems = [
    {
        name: 'USA',
        city: 'Washington',
        code: '',
        currency: '$'
    },
    {
        name: 'Germany',
        city: 'Berlin',
        code: '',
        currency: '€'
    },
    {
        name: 'Turkey',
        city: 'Istanbul',
        code: '',
        currency: '₺'
    }
]

const getFilteredItems = (customText = '', currencySelected = '') => {
    const myFilters = []
    if (customText !== '') {
        myFilters.push(x => x.name.includes(customText) || x.code.includes(customText) || x.city.includes(customText));
    }
    if (currencySelected !== '') {
        myFilters.push(x => x.currency === currencySelected);
    }
    return filteredItems.filter(x => myFilters.reduce((acc, myFilter) => acc && myFilter(x), true))
}

console.log(getFilteredItems('Istan'))
```